# How to carry forward an input value to the next step in a multi-step form?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to carry forward the value of `#firstname-input` and show it in `#firstname`. How to do so with JS?

I'm new to JS and tried multiple solutions but none worked.

Kindly help me with the JS code that will carry forward the value of the first name input in Step1 to the Step2 span.

```js
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".prev-btn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".next-btn");
let currentSection = 0;

function showSection(sectionIndex) {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".steps");
  sections[currentSection].classList.remove("active-step");
  sections[sectionIndex].classList.add("active-step");
  currentSection = sectionIndex;
}

function nextSection() {
  if (currentSection < 2) {
    showSection(currentSection + 1);
  }
}

function prevSection() {
  if (currentSection > 0) {
    showSection(currentSection - 1);
  }
}
```

```css
.steps{
    display: none;
}

.active-step{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <!-- Step1 -->
    <div class="steps active-step" id="step1">
        <div class="step-title">What's your first name?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="text" class="text-input" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname-input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection()" class="next-btn" id="step1-next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Step2 -->
    <div class="steps" id="step">
        <button onclick="prevSection()" class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
        <div class="step-title"><span id="firstname"></span>,which club you're in?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="text" class="text-input" placeholder="your club name" id="club-input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection()" class="next-btn" id="step1-next"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can read the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` using the [`.value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) of that element. In order to set the text content of an element, you can make use of [`.innerText` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) instead.

In addition, when having a `<button>` element inside of `<form>`, you might want to make sure the `type` property is set to `button` (eg. `<button type="button">...</button>`), this is because the default type is `submit` and it will trigger a submission of the form instead. (More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attributes)

The code below includes the fixes I mentioned above by listening to the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) of the input, this allow synchronising of the values from the input to the `<span>` element:

```js
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".prev-btn");
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".next-btn");
let currentSection = 0;

const firstNameInput = document.getElementById('firstname-input');
const firstNameSpans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.firstname'));
firstNameInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  firstNameSpans.forEach((firstNameSpan) => { firstNameSpan.innerText = firstNameInput.value; });
});

function showSection(sectionIndex) {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".steps");
  sections[currentSection].classList.remove("active-step");
  sections[sectionIndex].classList.add("active-step");
  currentSection = sectionIndex;
}

function nextSection() {
  if (currentSection < 2) {
    showSection(currentSection + 1);
  }
}

function prevSection() {
  if (currentSection > 0) {
    showSection(currentSection - 1);
  }
}
```

```css
.steps{
    display: none;
}

.active-step{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
    <!-- Step1 -->
    <div class="steps active-step" id="step1">
        <div class="step-title">What's your first name?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="text" class="text-input" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname-input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection()" type="button" class="next-btn" id="step1-next">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Step2 -->
    <div class="steps" id="step">
        <button onclick="prevSection()" type="button" class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
        <div class="step-title"><span class="firstname"></span>,which club you're in?</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="text" class="text-input" placeholder="your club name" id="club-input">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-next-box">
            <button onclick="nextSection()" type="button" class="next-btn" id="step1-next"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I added a Step3 in the form where the title should be "Firstname, what's your email?"
I used the same span with id #firstname but don't know why it is showing the value in Step2 but not in Step3. 
Can you please tell how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @Frankie, sure! In HTML, `id` must be unique across the whole application. In order to solve this, you can consider to use `class` instead, I have modified my code to work with `class` (Refer to `document.querySelectorAll` and the call of `forEach` to update all of them)

Comment: I want to make the next button go to the next step only after the input field of first name contains a value more than 1 character. How can I achieve that functionality?